# Conflicts using Brew for Node, NPM, Bower, etc. on Mac OS X 10.12.1

Tags: python, node.js, macos, npm, homebrew

I'm really sorry if this has already been answered in another thread, but I searched through the other Brew-Node (Mac) questions, and couldn't really find specifically what error I was receiving. I had already installed node/npm using Brew, but through the process of installing & playing with different packages/modules, I somehow seemed to screw everything up...

I'm not sure how to even explain the error, but I'll just show the CLI, and see if you guys can help.  Please be very specific, I'm new to Brew & Node in general, so please take that into consideration. Thanks to anyone with solutions or suggestions!

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2-config

Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. 

Run `brew link` on these:  node
```

This is what is displayed when I run `brew doctor`.

Then, there's this when I try to `brew install node` or `brew link --overwrite node`

```
  brew install node
Updating Homebrew...
To restore the stashed changes to /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core run:
  'cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core && git stash pop'
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> New Formulae
gst-rtsp-server
==> Updated Formulae
artifactory         exploitdb           libphonenumber      node@6
aws-sdk-cpp         freetds             llnode              nsd
babl                gimme               mawk                openvpn
bazel               gst-libav           mdv                 rancher-cli
chromedriver        heroku              neofetch            rancher-compose
closure-compiler    jasper              node                riemann
devd                javarepl            node-build          scamper
dovecot             kobalt              node@4              yarn
==> Deleted Formulae
pdksh

==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/node-7.2.1.sierra.bottle.ta
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring node-7.2.1.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
Target /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp

==> Using the sandbox
==> Caveats
Please note by default only English locale support is provided. If you need
full locale support you should either rebuild with full icu:
  `brew reinstall node --with-full-icu`
or add full icu data at runtime following:
  https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Intl#using-and-customizing-the-small-icu-build

Bash completion has been installed to: 
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/7.2.1: 3,884 files, 45.4M
$ brew link --overwrite node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/7.2.1... 
Error: Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.
```

I don't even know where to begin, I know it says conflicts with Python at top, but when I look in the PythonFramework (Mac Frameworks) folder, there's 3 different versions, and I don't know how to purge the conflicting files since the OS X won't let allow me to delete any, even with admin privileges.

This is **incredibly** frustrating, and I really need Node/NPM operating properly to work on my coding bootcamp projects. Thanks!